# How to enable the developer features in safariviewcontroller?

Tags: sfsafariviewcontroller

How to enable the developer features in `safariviewcontroller`? I've attempted to do it via `chrome://flags` but It doesn't seem to be present, are there any third party APIs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently available to be changed to date, try looking into other browsers